# search in large text file (java)

Tags: java, search, large-files

So, I have a dictionary-file with 70,000 lines which are ordered alphabetically. Each line is a separate word with translation. What would you recommend as the best practice for searching in such a file? I'm thinking about indexation of file but may be there're better ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, memory-map it using Java NIO's memory-mapped file support. Second, pre-process it to find all offsets at which a new entry starts. Finally, write some binary-search code that will find an entry. I think this could amount to the most lightweight and memory-efficient solution.

Lucene also employs skip-lists: you can additionally cache in-memory every 16th (or so) entry and use that in the first phase of the binary search. Then you'll have to go to the actual file only to zero in on the exact entry.

Comment: My file only weights 5 MB do you think memory-mapping will give me a much better perfomance? I've been thinking about jumping on entries and implementing a binary-search, but I've not found any tricks how to jump between lines of file in java, would you give me some tip?

Comment: I will use this code either for linux, either for android. I've heard that Lucene doesn't work properly on android.

Comment: I didn't recommend Lucene -- I just mentioned a trick it uses in its implementation, since in that respect it is a very good role model. Memory-mapped file is a breeze to use (it gives you an array-like view of the file) so it is a win-win for you: simpler API for better performance. Of course, you can always choose to load the complete file into RAM as a `String[70000][2]`. That kind of solution is just no fun, that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

The project that might  be a solution is [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)

Comment: You could improve the quality of your answer by explaining what Lucene does and why it is a good fit for this question.